# Prove that $ a × b = - (b × a) $ for all $ a,b \in \mathbb{R}^{3} $.

Tags: calculus, vectors

> **Problem:** Prove that $ a × b = - (b × a) $ for all $ a,b \in \mathbb{R}^{3} $.

I am stuck with this question and unaware of what to do or where to start. If someone could help me, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you define the cross product?

Comment: assume that a = (x, y, z) and b = (r, s, t) and then calculate a X b and b X a with the formula, and show that the equation applies

Comment: cross product is defined as u x v=[u2v3-u3v2,u3v1-u1v3,u1v2-v1u2]

Comment: @Joe OK. And how would you define $v\times u$?

Comment: @DanielY would this be right: [link](http://i.imgur.com/WSW3b9z.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\vec{a}=\langle a_1,a_2,a_3 \rangle$ and $\vec{b}=\langle b_1,b_2,b_3 \rangle$. Then,

$$\begin{align}
\vec{a}\times\vec{b}:&=\langle a_2b_3-a_3b_2,a_3b_1-a_1b_3,a_1b_2-a_2b_1\rangle\\
&=-\langle a_3b_2-a_2b_3,a_1b_3-a_3b_1,a_2b_1-a_1b_2\rangle\\
&=-\langle b_2a_3-b_3a_2,b_3a_1-b_1a_3,b_1a_2-b_2a_1\rangle\\
&=:-\vec{b}\times\vec{a}.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand this now.

Answer (score 0):

$a \times b$ is the unique vector $c$ such that:
$$\forall x \in \mathbb R^3, \det(a,b,x)=\langle c,x \rangle $$ where $\det$ is the determinant in a direct othonrmal basis.

Since: $\det(b,a,x)=-\det(a,b,x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb R^3$, wecan say that the unique  vector $c'$  such taht: $$\forall x \in \mathbb R^3, \det(b,a,x)= \langle c',x \rangle $$ is $-(a \times b)$ and conclude that $b \times a= - (a \times b) $